# jquery / js: can't make radio button clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

I have a little beginners problem, I can't make buttons inside a DIV clickable.

There is a top line of 5 buttons that work perfectly. On click a 2nd row will appear (and does), but I can't click them. Why is that?

This is the link:  https://jsfiddle.net/yello/1me8naee/

Code:

```js
       $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#div1,#div2,#div3').hide();
                $('#mod-7').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').show('fast');
                  $('#div2').hide('fast');
                  $('#div3').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#mod-7p').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').show('fast');
                  $('#div2').hide('fast');
                  $('#div3').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#mod-6s').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').hide('fast');
                  $('#div2').show('fast');
                  $('#div3').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#mod-6p').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').show('fast');
                  $('#div2').hide('fast');
                  $('#div3').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#mod-se').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').hide('fast');
                  $('#div2').hide('fast');
                  $('#div3').show('fast');
                });
              });
```

```css
.segmented {
  padding: 12px;
}

.segmented input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.segmented label {
  border: outset 1px silver;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.segmented input:checked + label {
  border: inset 1px silver;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="segmented">
  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Organisation" id="mod-7">
  <label for="mod-7">iPhone 7</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Users" id="mod-7p">
  <label for="mod-7p">iPhone 7 Plus</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Units" id="mod-6s">
  <label for="mod-6s">iPhone 6s</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Tags" id="mod-6sp">
  <label for="mod-6sp">iPhone 6s Plus</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Tags2" id="mod-se">
  <label for="mod-se">iPhone SE</label>


  <div align="center" style="padding:25px;width: 300px;">

    <div id="div1">
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="32" value="32">
      <label for="mem">32Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="128" value="128">
      <label for="mem">128Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="256" value="256">
      <label for="mem">256Gb</label>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="32" value="32">
      <label for="mem">32Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="128" value="128">
      <label for="mem">128Gb</label>
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="32" value="32">
      <label for="mem">32Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="64" value="64">
      <label for="mem">64Gb</label>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: what you expect on click of the 2nd row that is displayed? you have not attached any click event on them either.

Comment: Aim is that the lower button should go dark, same as the top row ones.

Comment: The `<label for="xxxx">` should reference the ID of the input and not the input name.

Comment: also, ids should be unique, you'd be better off using a data property for your 32-64... values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly fine. You only need to add ids to the labels.

E.g

```
   <div id="div1">
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="32" value="32">
      <label for="32">32Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="128" value="128">
      <label for="128">128Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="256" value="256">
      <label for="256">256Gb</label>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1me8naee/12/

Also you should have the ids specific to each model, otherwise there will be conflict e.g 32 iphone 6 and 32 iphone 7.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my jsfiddle - with your help it's working perfectly now!  https://jsfiddle.net/yello/1me8naee/

Answer (score 1):

in `for="mem3-64"` you have to give the id of the radio button like below.

```js
       $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#div1,#div2,#div3').hide();
                $('#mod-7').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').show('fast');
                  $('#div2').hide('fast');
                  $('#div3').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#mod-7p').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').show('fast');
                  $('#div2').hide('fast');
                  $('#div3').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#mod-6s').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').hide('fast');
                  $('#div2').show('fast');
                  $('#div3').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#mod-6p').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').show('fast');
                  $('#div2').hide('fast');
                  $('#div3').hide('fast');
                });
                $('#mod-se').click(function() {
                  $('#div1').hide('fast');
                  $('#div2').hide('fast');
                  $('#div3').show('fast');
                });
              });
```

```css
.segmented {
  padding: 12px;
}

.segmented input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.segmented label {
  border: outset 1px silver;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.segmented input:checked + label {
  border: inset 1px silver;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="segmented">
  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Organisation" id="mod-7">
  <label for="mod-7">iPhone 7</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Users" id="mod-7p">
  <label for="mod-7p">iPhone 7 Plus</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Units" id="mod-6s">
  <label for="mod-6s">iPhone 6s</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Tags" id="mod-6sp">
  <label for="mod-6sp">iPhone 6s Plus</label>

  <input type="radio" name="mod-1" value="Tags2" id="mod-se">
  <label for="mod-se">iPhone SE</label>


  <div align="center" style="padding:25px;width: 300px;">

    <div id="div1">
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="mem1-32" value="32">
      <label for="mem1-32">32Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="mem1-128" value="128">
      <label for="mem1-128">128Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="mem1-256" value="256">
      <label for="mem1-256">256Gb</label>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="mem2-32" value="32">
      <label for="mem2-32">32Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="mem2-128" value="128">
      <label for="mem2-128">128Gb</label>
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="mem3-32" value="32">
      <label for="mem3-32">32Gb</label>
      <input type="radio" name="mem" id="mem3-64" value="64">
      <label for="mem3-64">64Gb</label>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Don't you think it's better when all div names are the same? Because, otherwise if you change the model the clicked button will stay clicked, even though it's not visible. That might cause errors in the later FORM output.